# Trying to reject Negative values in an ArrayList Class

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm a really green amateur at java. I'm trying to build an ArrayList Class I can call from my main program to add user int values into the arrayList, reject negatives and then return the value. Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayInput {
   public static ArrayList<Integer> input() 
 { //This collect user CU and place in an ArrayList
    ArrayList<Integer> cus = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a # total for a single item and then press enter. To quit type exit: ");
    while (input.hasNextInt()){

    int value = input.nextInt();

    if (value < 0)
    {
    System.out.println("Error: must not be negative numbers: ");
    break; //<----- I know the break isn't right, and here's where I can't figure out
                    how to reject the negative and continue to collect positive #. 

    }
    else    
    {
    System.out.println("Enter a CU total for another single class and then press enter. To quit type exit: ");
    }
    cus.add(value);
}
return cus;
}
```

}

Any help would be app

Comment: Remove the break and put the add in your else statement block.

Comment: Use a do while loop for your value = input.nextInt(); to prompt the user as long as the value is negative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (value < 0)
{
    System.out.println("Error: must not be negative numbers: ");
}
else    
{
    cus.add(value);
    System.out.println("Enter a CU total for another single class and then press enter. To quit type exit: ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayInput {
   public static ArrayList<Integer> input() 
 { //This collect user CU and place in an ArrayList
    ArrayList<Integer> cus = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    int value;

    do { // do loop
         System.out.println("Enter a # total for a single item and then press enter. To quit type exit: ");
         value = input.nextInt();

         if (value < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: must not be negative numbers: ");
         }
    } while(value < 0); // loop as long as it's negative number

    System.out.println("Enter a CU total for another single class and then press enter. To quit type exit: ");
    cus.add(value);

return cus;
}
```

This should keep prompting the user for the value as long as the number is negative. However I noted that your "Enter a CU total for another single class and then press enter. To quit type exit: " wouldn't work properly. Guess you haven't implement it yet?

Things to note: this is not a main method. Therefore you shouldn't really get user to "continue to collect positive #.", however if that's what you really want you can use this loop method to keep asking the user. Also it would be better not to use Scanner to get input in this method. Instead get the input from the user in main method and call upon this method and passing in the input as an argument to add cus would be the right way of using methods.

Comment: `cus.add(value);` will add only last value you should put it inside loop.OP wants to reject Negative values ad add positive ones to ArrayList.Not a big Mistake Taking DownVote Back and still To quit type Exit will work :)

Comment: WoW, I got response quicker than I thought I would.Thanks that means a lot. Maybe I can clarify what I'm doing. I'm calling this arrayList class. I'm wanting it to prompt the user to enter positive ints and if there's negatives reject it, but then prompt the user to try again. I still need to figure out how to exit out after they're done entering the int into the arrayList. 

I think I'm making this harder than what It should be, that's what causing me to get lost.

Comment: @TAsk putting inside cus.add(value); inside the loop will get add negative value. I'm looping the input value by user and keep requesting for the input value till user input a positive value then it will do the necessary add. This is what the user wants. However I noted that this is a method so he shouldn't really get the inputs, your answer would be the more correct way of using the method. But this is what OPs want which is not using the correct way of writing methods.

Comment: @user3591640 keep your method short. You should do the re-prompting and checking of negative value in the main method. And instead your this method should take in the input value as an argument to do cus.add instead. So you don't really need to declare additional Scanner object to get the user input. This will make your codes neater. Also while (input.hasNextInt()){ } I'm not sure why you are using the loop for, but my guess is it will either return hit an error or return a false which will makes the code not running at all.

Comment: @Sky Many thanks. I'm 6 weeks into learning Java, so neat code is still something I'm struggling with. I'm trying to consume as much info as possible. Thank you for your help, I've added you suggestions to my overflowing notebook. Thanks for your help. I think I have it working.